# Is there a way to dynamically refresh the less command?

Tags: less, watch

I like the `watch` command, but it has [its limitations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3842/how-can-i-scroll-within-the-output-of-my-watch-command).

I'm curious to know whether I could mimic the functionality of `watch` with `less`. I'm mainly looking for the ability to scroll through my directory as it dynamically gets modified via a running script.

Comment: I am looking for `tail -f foo.log | grep bar`, and to be able to dynamically change the grep command with restarting the tail/grep pipeline.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

In `less`, you can type `F` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)  to keep reading at the end of a file (like `tail -f`); you can type `:e` and a file name to view a different file, but unfortunately, if you enter the name of the current file, `less` doesn't reload the file. However there's a trick to make it re-read the current file, suggested by [sabgenton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/67483/sabgenton): **type `:e` and enter the name of a non-existent file**; that causes less to display an error message and then reload the current file.

If you're looking for an alternative to `watch ls`, here are a few:

- Modern file managers (e.g. Nautilus, Thunar, Konqueror, Dolphin, Finder) refresh views in real time.
- Emacs doesn't have real-time refresh, but with `auto-revert-mode`, it will reload the file or directory every 5 seconds (the delay is configurable).
- Although w3m is primarily a web browser, it makes a passable directory and text file viewer. Press `R` to reload the (local) URL.

Comment: For me :e randomnamejkdlfjldf  fails to load the non-existent  filename then reloads back to the current file :D

Comment: @sabgenton Thanks, I didn't know that. That's a great trick. I added it to my answer, but you could post it as an answer of your own (which I hope Zaid would accept).

Comment: What if the file contents change but changes aren't necessarily appended. As in the file contents may be replaced completely, or partially. Does `less +F` deal with such a thing?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai No, `less +F` only watches for appended content. Use `:e nonexistentfile` to re-read completely changed input.

Comment: Is there a command line flag for that?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai No. If you want automatic refresh, I think you need a fancier tool like Emacs with autorevert mode, or else send the `:e` automatically (like http://askubuntu.com/questions/355301/terminal-web-browser-page-reload).

Comment: Turns out that vim has `autoread` and `checktime`.

Comment: The answer from @destenson should also be added/linked to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330009/13676 This is the real answer, since it turns out that less also has a 'R' command to 'Refresh' the file.

Comment: @PaulWagland No, `R` doesn't reliably refresh the file. It refreshes the screen, and wipes some input buffers, but it doesn't actually reload data from the file in all circumstances (only if the file is large? I didn't dig deeply into the code).

Comment: @Gilles Ah. OK, the test that I was doing was indeed with a large (15Gb!!) file, so that might explain why I always saw the refresh. Thanks for the update.

Comment: I wish I could give you a +1 for every time I forget about this and find myself here again. :D

Comment: This solution will work when `R` doesn't: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-refresh-the-less-command/445633#445633

Comment: Sadly, this trick (:e *gibberish*) no longer seems to work. In `less` ver 487 on my Raspberry Pi, I pipe a `ls -l` to `less`, then I move one of the files in the listing. The display *appears* to refresh, but the file I moved is still in the listing.

Comment: @Seamus You mean `ls -l | less` ? This has never worked and cannot possibly work. The `ls` command has already run and there is no instruction to run it again. The question was about re-reading a file.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': I did not know that - thanks. Why couldn't it work - are you saying that this intrinsically cannot be done? It can run other commands when command output is piped to it - e.g. search (?). I'm not suggesting that it *should* be done, but I don't understand why it "cannot be done". And what is the oft-repeated statement, ["everything's a file"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)? I guess in this case, the file would need refreshing with another `ls -l`, but is that impossible?

Comment: @Seamus `less` can run other commands, but here nothing is instructing it to. It's reading from a pipe and it doesn't know what is writing to the pipe. All it can do is keep reading from the pipe, but that does nothing since nothing is writing to the pipe anymore.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': Yeah, I got that - it didn't occur to me at first, but finally did while writing the last comment. My only point was that I can't see why it's impossible for `less` to learn how it was spawned - I was thinking of the `history` command specifically, but thought there must be other ways also. But you've indulged my curiosity long enough, so please don't feel compelled to reply.

Answer (score 83):

<kbd>Shift+F</kbd> will make `less` similar to the command `tail -f`. That is, it gets refreshed if more data is appended to the file.

Comment: Note that this *only* works for appends. If lines are removed or edited in-place, `less` won't show those changes.

Comment: How do I stop following mode and re-enter scrollable mode?

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>

Comment: balki My experience is that this kills the command piping the data if you are using `$COMMAND | less`. I wonder if there is a nice way around this? You can do stuff like `$COMMAND > /tmp/file & less /tmp/file` but that's not very nice.

Comment: @AttRigh I never killed my command (however i read logs of running commands this way, i don't pipe into less, technically)

Answer (score 57):

Simply type:

```
less +F filename
```

This emulates pressing "F" within the editor.

Comment: Thanks; added the alias `alias check="less +F"` to my `.bashrc`.

Comment: Same as <kbd>Shift+F</kbd>  when already in `less`, for followers...

Answer (score 30):

`man` pages can be very informative. Don't be intimidated by them. Among everything else, `man less` says you can use the `R` command to:

```
   R      Repaint the screen, discarding any buffered input.  Useful if the file is changing while it is being viewed.
```

(I realize this question is over 6 years old, but it comes up on google searches, so I'm not the only one that clicked the link to get here.)

Comment: This repaints the screen in case it was disrupted by output from another program. It doesn't consistently reload the file. I haven't dug deeply into the code to see what it does, experimentally short files don't get reloaded. I am definitely not intimidated by man pages and I say this description is poorly worded: “repaint” does not convey that input is re-read, and the actual behavior does not quite fit “useful if the file is changing” (maybe it's a bug? I don't know since I don't know what the command is supposed to do)..

Comment: I'm no expert, and haven't read less's source code either, but what it does is forget what it already knows about the file & reloads it, refreshing its output based on the input it reloads. The question reads "Is there a way to dynamically refresh the less command?" If I had read the question's explanation more thoroughly before answering, I might not have answered, since they go on to say they want "to scroll through my directory as it dynamically gets modified via a running script." less wouldn't be the right command for that.

Comment: Works fine for me, even when using files 3 bytes long. I can't imagine why it wouldn't work for larger files too.

Comment: Great! For me it works for both short and long files. I just noticed two possible problems: 1. `less` did not reopen the file using its filename - i.e. when the inode of the file changed (like in overwriting the file using `mv`) then the old file content stayed (probably the old inode was reread) --- 2. The first displayed line probably starts at the same byte offset as in the original file content. So when the line lengths change the first displayed line could be incomplete and the displayed lines could move up / down.

Comment: `R` doesn't always work. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-refresh-the-less-command/445633#445633

Comment: Like this trick. But as much effort as Q and rerun less.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me at all... (linux, less a file, modify using vi in another terminal)...

Comment: This is better than `G` when you need to stay where you were initially. If I just want the end, then `G` is preferable. But this one is very useful.

Answer (score 12):

`R` for repaint does not always reload the file.<sup>[1]</sup>

A workaround that always reloads the file is to press `hq`, which will open the Help page, then quit. It has a side effect of forcing the file to reload.

---

[1] Here are some examples of situations that `R` do and do not reload:

- `>` and `>>` changes: DO get reloaded
- `sed -i`, gEdit, TextEdit: DO NOT get reloaded
- On Linux, `vi` changes: DO get reloaded
- On Mac, `vi` changes: DO NOT get reloaded

I believe the difference comes down to whether the inode changes (you can check with `ls -i foo.txt`). If the inode changes, then `R` will not work.

Comment: I really like the `hq` hack, but note that if you happen to be viewing the end of a file that gets shorter, `less` will fail out. (Really, if you happen to be seeked anywhere past the end of the new file) With one more key, you can avoid that crash: `ghq`.

Answer (score 7):

I normally just type <kbd>G</kbd> to tail the output on a one-time basis. I find it especially helpful over a a network file system like CIFS.

Comment: This is more of an on-demand refresh of the file opened with less. In addition to jumping to the end of the file, it also reloads the file if it has changed.

Comment: Thanks. First time it didn't refresh for me, but now it seems to work properly. In the man it's not written that it refreshes the file. `man less`: 'G or > or ESC-> Go to line N in the file, default the end of the file.' I delete my old wrong comments here, sorry for them.

Comment: BTW, what do you call a 'one-time basis'? The maintainer of `less`, Mark Nudelman, replied the following: "The G command does not normally force a re-read of the file like the R command does. It may seem do that if the end of the file has not yet been read when G is invoked, so that jumping to the end of the file must read the data there for the first time.  For example, if you jump to the end with G, then jump back to the beginning with 1G, then another program modifies the data at the end of the file (without changing the length), " (cont)

Comment: (cont) "then you jump to the end again with G, you will not see the modified data. But if you don't jump to the end and back to the beginning, then the first time you execute the G command it must read the data there for the first time, and of course it will see any modifications that have happened since less was first invoked. "

Comment: In this case I mentioned it being a _one-time_ refresh as opposed to a _dynamic_ refresh, which is part of what the original question is asking.

Answer (score 5):

The "F" key when running `less` will do a "follow" similar to `tail -f`, but I'm not sure if that will achieve what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe it to `tail -f` instead, it would result in you following the output. You'd be losing the ability to move (scroll) through your output though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vim to read the file then add the following mapping to your `.vimrc` file and you can easily reload a file with <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>:

```
let mapleader = ","
nnoremap <leader>r :edit <CR>
```

Note if you edited the file already, vim will complain. Just change to

```
let mapleader = ","
nnoremap <leader>r :edit! <CR>
```

To ignore changes.

Comment: They'll have to pry `vim` from your cold, dead hands. The context of the question is about `less`, but as someone with _monomaniacal_ tendencies myself, I sympathise!

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this problem using a shell script that auto-reloads `less` on exit:

```
while true; do less -K file.txt || exit; done
```

With this script, I can hit `q` to reload the file, and `CTRL+C` to exit back to the bash shell. The `CTRL+C` behavior is enabled via the **`-K`** option. Your last search term will be preserved.

This can be further refactored by using the colon (`:`) to create an empty expression, via `do :` ...

```
while less -K file.txt; do : ; done
```

#### Drawbacks

The current viewing position will always be rest to line 0.

#### Practical Example using `mintty`

In my windows (GitBash) environment I set up a script that opens a new terminal window (mintty) for less-viewing a file:

```
lesswin() { mintty bash -c "while less -K \"$@\"; do : ; done;" & }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this thread like anyone else.
I would like to add the solution of when you are already at the end of the file, using 'g' followed by 'G' will force a refresh of the file.

I ended up making a macro button for this in my terminal program (SecureCRT).
The macro is simply 'gG'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the inotify-tools to watch for directory changes and rerun `ls` every time a file is written to:

```bash
inotifywait -mqe CLOSE_WRITE <directory-path> | while read; do clear; ls <directory-path>; done
```

`inotifywait` can also be used to watch an overwritten file:

```bash
inotifywait -mqe MODIFY <file-path> | while read; do clear; cat <file-path>; done
```