# Repeating a text-output terminal command, in a scrollable ncurses-like interface?

Tags: terminal, watch

`man ps` says:

> If you want a repetitive update of the selection and the displayed information, use top(1) instead.

... however, in some cases, I don't like the output of `top` - I would instead like to have the output exactly the same as `ps axf`:

```
$ ps axf
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S      0:06  \_ [ksoftirqd/0]
    6 ?        S      0:00  \_ [migration/0]
   11 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [cpuset]
   12 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [khelper]
   13 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [netns]
   15 ?        S      0:00  \_ [sync_supers]
   16 ?        S      0:00  \_ [bdi-default]
   17 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [kintegrityd]
   18 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [kblockd]
   19 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [kacpid]
   20 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [kacpi_notify]
   21 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [kacpi_hotplug]
   22 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [ata_sff]
   23 ?        S      0:00  \_ [khubd]
   24 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [md]
   26 ?        S      0:00  \_ [khungtaskd]
   27 ?        S      0:01  \_ [kswapd0]
   28 ?        SN     0:00  \_ [ksmd]
   29 ?        S      0:00  \_ [fsnotify_mark]
   30 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [aio]
   31 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ecryptfs-kthrea]
   32 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [crypto]
   36 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [kthrotld]
   38 ?        S      0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_0]
   39 ?        S      0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_1]
   40 ?        S<     0:00  \_ [kmpathd]
...
```

Now, running `ps axf` repeatedly is not a problem (plenty of suggestions on [Repeat a Unix command every x seconds forever - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever)); however, as the above snippet shows, its output can be quite larger than the size of a terminal window.

So I was wondering - is there a program which can run a command repeatedly, and collect its output, and display it in something like an `ncurses` window? I'd ideally like to set `ps axf` to refresh at half a second - and I'd like to have scrolling (given that the output will overflow terminal window bounds), however, such that if the text display starts vertically from, say, line 6 on top, it stays at that position - even if the latest output of the command has more (or less) lines of text in it than the previous one.

I hoped `screen` may do something like this, but then, I don't think it implements any scrolling behavior... Is there a program out there that does something like this?

Comment: Does `watch -n 0.5 ps axf` do what you want?

Comment: You're looking for something like `watch` but unfortunately there's no scrolling as you describe it there.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkPlotnick and @Marki - unfortunately, there seems to be no scrolling behavior with `watch`, although, at least it keeps the start of output on top of terminal...

Comment: You can scroll in screen, but it's a bit cumbersome (press `C-a ESC`, then you can scroll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular point of contention has come up here on U&L a couple of times before. Mainly around the tool `watch`, which doesn't have this feature.

- [How can I scroll within the output of my watch command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3842/how-can-i-scroll-within-the-output-of-my-watch-command)
- [Is there a way to dynamically refresh the less command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-refresh-the-less-command)
- [Is there a paging version of `watch`?](https://serverfault.com/questions/50772/is-there-a-paging-version-of-watch)

Generally you have 3 options.

1. Use `watch` with this limitation
2. Use a alternative script ([mywatch.sh](https://serverfault.com/a/53282/2518) or [watchless](https://serverfault.com/a/50774/2518)) or tool such as [`pwatch`](https://github.com/jyapayne/UnixWatchCommandOutput)
3. Use an alternative tool to `ps`, such as `htop` or `atop`

So I would encourage you to let go of `ps` and use it for what it is. A quick way to get at the state of things when in a shell. If you want to "watch" the state of the various processes running on a system use a tool such as `htop`. It has a "tree" view similar to the one you're asking about and you can scroll through the output.

**NOTE:** To toggle "treeview" simply hit the <kbd>t</kbd> key while in `htop`.

[image: ss of htop]

#### Kernel thread in htop?

If you'd like to see Kernel Thread in `htop` you can enable them. They're disabled by default. There are 2 ways to do this. You can toggle them on and off using the keyborad shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

It's also accessible from the *Setup* menu, <kbd>F2</kbd>. Once you're in the *Setup* menu you can use the arrow keys (←,↑,→,↓) to move around, and to mark things you use the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. Once you've picked your changes, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get out.

[image: ss #2]

**NOTE:** In the above screenshot, **#1** shows you're in the *Setup menu*. **#2** shows we've used the ↑ and ↓ arrow keys to move to *Display Options*. To access these options, you'd use the ← and → arrow keys to move over to the "choices" part of the menu, followed by ↑ and ↓ arrows to "select". Once you've selected an option you can use the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to toggle it.

#### References

- [System Monitoring Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_monitor)
- [Why doesn't htop display the same processes as top?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145707/why-doesnt-htop-display-the-same-processes-as-top)

Comment: Many thanks for that answer @slm - it explains well that what is a "state of the art" for this problem (which I wasn't aware of) - so I accepted it for now. I got both `atop` and `htop` - and it seems, none of them report `kthreadd` and its "dependencies"; and that is a part of what I need this for (and which is why I wanted a "generic" application which gives one a `curses` scrolling window). Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: PS: [pwatch](https://github.com/jyapayne/UnixWatchCommandOutput) seems to be able to do what I wanted; except it needs handlers for proper termination of `ncurses`; it also (currently) terminates prematurely if one goes above a certain line in the `ps axf` output (though scrolling works). But otherwise, that was what I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: PSS: [Multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/manual.php) linked from one of the pages on this answer also looks neat, but it needs to be built from source (for me, `libncursesw5-dev` was also needed); but unfortunately it can scroll "only the last 100 lines", and refresh of the command kills the scroll window (as of v6.0).

Comment: @sdaau - you can control the scrollback using the `-mb x` and `M lines` switches on `multitail`. I only have 5.2.13 in repos.

Comment: @sdaau - Did you try something like this? `multitail -R 2 -l "ps axf"`.

Comment: @sdaau - see updates regarding kthreads.