# Read special keys in bash

Tags: bash, keyboard

I am playing with a script that, among other things, list a selection-list. As in:

```
1) Item 1              # (highlighted)
2) Item 2
3) Item 3              # (selected)
4) Item 4
```

- When user press `down-arrow` next items is highlighted
- When user press `up-arrow` previous items is highlighted
- etc.
- When user press `tab` item is selected
- When user press `shift+tab` all items are selected / deselected
- When user press `ctrl+a` all items are selected
- ...

This works fine as of current use, which is my personal use where input is filtered by my own setup.

Question is how to make this reliable across various terminals.

---

I use a somewhat hackish solution to read input:

```
while read -rsn1 k # Read one key (first byte in key press)
do
    case "$k" in
    [[:graph:]])
        # Normal input handling
        ;;
    $'\x09') # TAB
        # Routine for selecting current item
        ;;
    $'\x7f') # Back-Space
        # Routine for back-space
        ;;
    $'\x01') # Ctrl+A
        # Routine for ctrl+a
        ;;
    ...
    $'\x1b') # ESC
        read -rsn1 k
        [ "$k" == "" ] && return    # Esc-Key
        [ "$k" == "[" ] && read -rsn1 k
        [ "$k" == "O" ] && read -rsn1 k
        case "$k" in
        A) # Up
            # Routine for handling arrow-up-key
            ;;
        B) # Down
            # Routine for handling arrow-down-key
            ;;
        ...
        esac
        read -rsn4 -t .1 # Try to flush out other sequences ...
    esac
done
```

And so on.

---

As mentioned, question is how to make this reliable across various terminals: i.e. what byte sequences define a specific key. Is it even feasible in bash?

One thought was to use either `tput` or `infocmp` and filter by the result given by that. I am however in a snag there as both `tput` and `infocmp` differ from what I actually read when actually pressing keys. Same goes for example using C over bash.

```
for t in $(find /lib/terminfo -type f -printf "%f\n"); { 
    printf "%s\n" "$t:"; 
    infocmp -L1 $t | grep -E 'key_(left|right|up|down|home|end)';
}
```

Yield sequences read as defined for for example `linux`, but not `xterm`, which is what is set by `TERM`.

E.g. arrow left:

- `tput` / `infocmp`: `\x1 O D`
- `read`: `\x1 [ D`

What am I missing?

Comment: no need to reinvent the wheel, [iselect](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/tool/iselect/) already does this.  Alternatively, use one of the `dialog` variants, or use a language with decent `ncurses` support (perl or python for example, if you want to stick with "scripting" languages).

Comment: Note that `zsh` has builtin curses support (in the zsh/curses module) in addition to basic terminfo querying with its `echoti` builtin and `$terminfo` associative array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are missing is that most terminal descriptions (`linux` is in the minority here, owing to the pervasive use of hard-coded strings in `.inputrc`) use *application mode* for special keys.  That makes cursor-keys as shown by `tput` and `infocmp` differ from what your (uninitialized) terminal sends.  curses applications always initialize the terminal, and the terminal data base is used for *that* purpose.

`dialog` has its uses, but does not directly address this question.  On the other hand, it is cumbersome (technically *doable*, rarely *done*) to provide a bash-only solution.  Generally we use other languages to do this.

The problem with reading special keys is that they often are multiple bytes, including awkward characters such as <kbd>escape</kbd> and <kbd>~</kbd>.  You can *do* this with bash, but then you have to solve the problem of portably determining what special key this was.

`dialog` both handles input of special keys and takes over (temporarily) your display.  If you really want a simple command-line program, that isn't `dialog`.

Here is a simple program in C which reads a special key and prints it in *printable* (and portable) form:

```
#include <curses.h>

int
main(void)
{   
    int ch;
    const char *result;
    char buffer[80];

    filter();
    newterm(NULL, stderr, stdin);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    ch = getch();
    if ((result = keyname(ch)) == 0) {
        /* ncurses does the whole thing, other implementations need this */
        if ((result = unctrl((chtype)ch)) == 0) {
            sprintf(buffer, "%#x", ch);
            result = buffer;
        }
    }
    endwin();
    printf("%s\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Supposing this were called `tgetch`, you would use it in your script like this:

```
case $(tgetch 2>/dev/null) in
KEY_UP)
   echo "got cursor-up"
   ;;
KEY_BACKSPACE|"^H")
   echo "got backspace"
   ;;
esac
```

Further reading:

- [My cursor keys do not work](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode) (ncurses FAQ)
- [**`dialog`** — Script-driven curses widgets (application and library)](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html)
- [keyname/key_name](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-keyname_key_name)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, `inputrc` was indeed the culprit I was looking for. Have to look at it some more. Have considered going python or C, but find it fun to hack on as a bash script as well. I also tried to have a look at the ncurses source to see if I could extract the bits I need – but after quite some time digging the source I left it on ice. The *"project"* started out as a simple command, then became a simple interactive script, and then extended on that again. Somewhere along the way I should have gone *other language*,but got a bit stubborn (and as mentioned it is fun to hack on in bash 2 :)

Comment: Found the sequences in, among others, `/usr/share/doc/readline-common/inputrc.arrows`. As I already have a generic *"read_key"* function that I use across the script I hoped there was a easier way to define the sequences (in the script) from what is actually presented when a key is pressed. I.e. similar to extracting definitions from `infocmp`. But guess not and either have to leave it as is or move on to another language. A compromise could of course be to use your, nice, C-snippet. But then I can write the whole thing in C instead. (Sorry for oversharing.)

Comment: Is that the complete C code? I get about a dozen errors when I try compiling this using gcc on Debian 9

Comment: You probably omitted the `-lncurses`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using `dialog`? It comes standard with most Linux distros and can create all kinds of text-based dialogs, including checklists.

For example:

```
exec 3>&1 # open temporary file handle and redirect it to stdout

#                           type      title        width height n-items    
items=$(dialog --no-lines --checklist "Title here" 20    70     4 \
          1 "Item 1" on \
          2 "Item 2" off \
          3 "Item 3" on \
          4 "Item 4" off \
            2>&1 1>&3) # redirect stderr to stdout to catch output, 
                       # redirect stdout to temporary file
selected_OK=$? # store result value
exec 3>&- # close new file handle 

# handle output
if [ $selected_OK = 0 ]; then
    echo "OK was selected."
    for item in $items; do
        echo "Item $item was selected."
    done
else
    echo "Cancel was selected."
fi
```

You'll get something like this:

[image]

And the output will be:

```
 OK was selected.
 Item 1 was selected.
 Item 3 was selected.
```

(or whichever items you selected).

`man dialog` will get you information on the other kinds of dialogs you can create, and how to customize the appearance.

Comment: +1 for effort, but Dickey was more to the point of what I'm asking. For one  to what the issue described was – in a more general sense, the list was merely to give some context. Secondly I have had a quick look at dialog – and admittedly I have not looked at it thoroughly, my case, to expand on it, is a front for a sqlite database with several thousand records where I have for example Page-Up/Down to scroll trough selection. Scroll-region, scroll-buffer, a status line, a ex line with modal input, sub functions for filtering etc. In short it might sound complex, but is rather simple …

Comment: … but dialog did not quite seem to meet the needs, or be somewhat cumbersome for my case.

Comment: @user367890 your application sounds like a perfect match for the perl `Curses`, `DBI`, and `DBD::SQLite` modules.  or their python equivalents.

Comment: @cas: Yes. Have written similar applications using python and C earlier – though I have to re-learn a lot of it. This "project" is more of an adventure into bash possibilities and "for the fun of it" :) Though I am getting close to abandoning it or port it to another language. Thanks for input.