# Scrollable version of `watch`

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, watch

We need to track a status file that is rewritten every few seconds by a server process. The `watch` command works beautifully for this (i.e. `watch cat file.txt`), except now the table is several pages long (even on a rotated wide-screen display).  We have a dedicated display/monitor that runs this command continuously and we need to be able to scroll up and down the file to find pertinent status values.
I will also note that we are not running `screen` or `tmux` since we have dedicated the entire monitor to this status file.

I've searched on the topic (with the best discussion [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3842/how-can-i-scroll-within-the-output-of-my-watch-command)) but none of the code works on our system (Ubuntu 20).  For example:

- `swatch` runs and scrolls, but after a few minutes the text gets shredded with each update and becomes unreadable
- `pwatch` flickers so badly its not watchable (the `watch` command by itself has perfectly smooth updates)
- `watch "cat file | tail -n $(($LINES - 2))"` has a static offset and does not scroll
- `watchall` does not actually scroll (I think there is `curses` error also)

So now I'm posing the question again.  Has anyone found a scrollable version of `watch` that will work on Ubuntu?
Thanks.

Comment: How about `watch 'cmd | pr -t2'` or run within `screen` with a screen size bigger than the host terminal's

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scroll within the output of my watch command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3842/how-can-i-scroll-within-the-output-of-my-watch-command)

Answer (score 2):

How often do you need to scroll the screen, and how often do you need the view to update? If you anticipate needing to scroll, I imagine you're going to spend more than a few seconds looking at any particular instance of the file. Something like the following could work:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

file="${1}"
while true; do
  timeout 60s less "${file}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The page is more of a text-based dashboard with continuously updated measured parameters, so we do indeed need to stare at it for a while as we track changing values.  And we also need to scroll up and down.  At some point this should be moved to a real dashboard, but for now it so much faster to build these with text blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some kind of log viewer app like klogg would be useful for your use case. https://klogg.filimonov.dev/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`viddy`](https://github.com/sachaos/viddy).

It's a binary that has the basic features of original watch command, including color output and diff highlight, but allows scroll and has a couple more cool features including text search and time machine mode, which allows one go back to the previous versions of the output.

The current one-liner to install it is

```
wget -O viddy.tar.gz https://github.com/sachaos/viddy/releases/download/v0.3.6/viddy_0.3.6_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz && tar xvf viddy.tar.gz && sudo mv viddy /usr/local/bin
```

And then you can use it like, for example

```
viddy -d -n 1 cat file.txt
```

to get the file contents every second and to highlight the changes. While viddy is running, press `?` to get the keyboard shortcuts.

`viddy` cmd options:

```
$ viddy -h

Usage:
 viddy [options] command

Options:
  -b, --bell                 ring terminal bell changes between updates
  -d, --differences          highlight changes between updates
  -n, --interval <interval>  seconds to wait between updates (default "2s")
  -p, --precise              attempt run command in precise intervals
  -c, --clockwork            run command in precise intervals forcibly
  -t, --no-title             turn off header
  --shell                    shell (default "sh")
  --shell-options            additional shell options
  --unfold                   unfold command result
  --pty                      run on pty (experimental, not for Windows)
```